# Ubuntu Server 22.04 persistent network settings

Tags: networking, server, 22.04

I have Ubuntu 22.04 installed. I kept getting  dropped packets warning from [Netdata](https://community.netdata.cloud/t/inbound-packets-dropped-ratio/1899). After running;

```
ethtool -g eno1                         
Ring parameters for eno1:
Pre-set maximums:
RX:             4096
RX Mini:        n/a
RX Jumbo:       n/a
TX:             4096
Current hardware settings:
RX:             256
RX Mini:        n/a
RX Jumbo:       n/a
TX:             256
```

I changed the network settings with;

```
sudo ethtool -G eno1 rx 4096 && sudo ethtool -G eno1 tx 4096
```

This appears to have solved the issue, but `ethtool` is not persistent over a reboot. I cannot find the Ubuntu 22.04 file I need to change in order to make the changes persistent.

Please advise

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://michael.mulqueen.me.uk/2018/08/disable-offloading-netplan-ubuntu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue using [Network Manager Dispatcher](https://developer-old.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/NetworkManager.html) functionality. This service allows a script to be executed when network events occurs. We can add a script that checks the ring buffer settings when an interface comes "up" and action the command to set the RX and TX buffers to max if needed.

To test this, copy the script [99-ringconf](https://github.com/StudentSA/linux/raw/main/scripts/99-ringconf) to location:

```
/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d
```

ensure the file has correct ownership and permissions:

```
sudo chown root:root /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99-ringconf
sudo chmod 755 /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99-ringconf
```

Now reboot to test persistence. log lines are also in:

```
/var/log/syslog
```

to check what the script is working.